# "By which time" meaning

Tags: word-meaning

> *She finally called a solicitor, **by which time** the hotel had been closed down*

What does the the relative clause in the above sentence exactly mean?

Does that sentence have the same meaning with this sentence: *By the time she finally called a solicitor, the hotel had been closed*

In relative clause, except the word "time", Do we use other nouns together with "which"?

Answer (score 2):

"By which time" refers to at/before a particular time that has previously been mentioned. In the sentence, it's the time she finally called the solicitor.